# hibernate throwing constructor error, multiple fields

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate, constructor

I modified some working code in a class called Alignment to include a 4th column. 
Alignment is used in a list by another class so Alignment is defined as @embedded. In the using class the columns are defined using AttributeOverrides.

The frustrating thing is that it works in the original state with 3 columns. I added the 4th column "origin" and get this error when creating the list:

```
     demo.admin Fluence 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1 /ia/secure/assignment/list.action] [36mo.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper
[0;39m : Unknown column 'alignments0_.origin' in 'field list'

10-Oct-2018 14:40:27.571 SEVERE [tomcat-http--3] org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke Servlet.service() for servlet [jsp] threw exception
 com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'alignments0_.origin' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
```

The list that uses Alignment is defined as:

```
@ElementCollection(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@OrderColumn(name = "order_index")
@CollectionTable(
  name = "alignment",
  joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id", 
   nullable = false))
@AttributeOverrides({
  @AttributeOverride(name = "guid", column = @Column(name = "guid")),
  @AttributeOverride(name = "setName", column = @Column(name = "set_name")),
  @AttributeOverride(name = "subject", column = @Column(name = "subject")),
  @AttributeOverride(name = "origin", column = @Column(name = "origin"))
 })
@Cache(usage = 
CacheConcurrencyStrategy.NONSTRICT_READ_WRITE)
public List<Alignment> getAlignments() {
  return this.alignments;
}
```

Alignment's constructors are:

```
@Embeddable
public class Alignment implements Serializable {

public static String MANUAL = "manual";
public static String AUTO = "auto";

public Alignment() {  }

public Alignment(Standard standard) {
  this.guid = standard.getGuid();
  this.setName = standard.getStandardSet();
  this.subject = standard.getSubjectArea();
  this.origin = AUTO;
}

public Alignment(String guid, String setName, 
  SubjectArea subject) {
  this.guid = guid;
  this.setName = setName;
  this.subject = subject;
  this.origin = AUTO;
}

public Alignment(String guid, String setName, 
  SubjectArea subject, String origin) {
  this.guid = guid;
  this.setName = setName;
  this.subject = subject;
  this.origin = origin;
}
```

Very frustrating as the 3 element constructor was working fine while the 4 element constructor is not. 
The select that retrieves the data does not reference this table since it is an  Embedded class to Alignment based on the hibernate attributes defined above.

The select has not been changed and origin was added to the alignment table as a varchar(10).

What am I missing here?

Comment: How does the SQL statement look like when increasing Hibernate log level for org.hibernate.SQL logger?

Comment: The SQL does not explicitly reference the Alignment table since it is embedded inside a containing class. The sql simply uses {assignment.*}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So it was not a hibernate problem at all. 
The Alignment class was embedded in several classes throughout the system and they pointed to several different tables. Add the origin column to these tables and voila! everything works fine.

Now to decide if this is a good design or no.

Anyone know if hibenate has an override to NOT use a column in a class when fetching?